# Deleting items from list

Tags: android, sqlite

I have list items with check boxes, when user selects any check box it should enable menu like icons at image footer. Now my question is if I want to delete any item from list how can I delete that particular item by clicking delete icon which is at bottom of the screen?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use listview.getCheckedItemPositions() and delete the positions which are selected. below is an example, which I have used in my one of the app.

```
SparseBooleanArray selected = lvcontacts.getCheckedItemPositions();
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
            if (selected != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
                    if (selected.get(i)) {
                        String s[] = { contacts.get(i).getName(),
                                contacts.get(i).getEmail(),
                                contacts.get(i).getNumber() };
                        db.delete("Contacts", "name=? and email=? and phone=?",
                                s);
                        Utils.printLog("Contacts while Delete", s[0] + "$"
                                + s[1] + "$" + s[2]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for deleting the Checked items in the List..

```
final int itemCount = getListView().getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
   if (checkedItemPositions.get(i)) {
       list.remove(i);
   } 
}
```